# Two identical strings are "not equal". Why?

Tags: powershell, logic

[image]

Im trying to figure out why these two strings are not equal. Is there a better operator I should use?

$lastupdated = invoke-webrequest -uri $source | Out-String -Stream | Select-String Last-Modified

$storeddate = get-content C:\windows\file.txt

Comment: those are `DateTime` objects not strings, which is why they aren't working the way you want them to

Comment: How do you determine it concerns `string` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root Cause

Based on how you're initialising `$storeaddate`...

```
$storeddate = get-content C:\windows\file.txt
```

... I'm going to assume your file has just got a single line of text with something like this in it..

```
Last-Modified     Web 17, May 2023 23:27:24 GMT
```

... which makes it a `[string]` instance.

Whereas `$lastupdated` is initialised like this:

```
$lastupdated = invoke-webrequest -uri $source | Out-String -Stream | Select-String Last-Modified
```

which means it's a [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) object because that's what `Select-String` returns.

You can check that with this:

```
$lastupdated.GetType().FullName

# Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo
```

and you can see more details with this:

```
$lastupdated | fl *

# IgnoreCase : True
# LineNumber : 1
# Line       : Last-Modified     Web 17, May 2023 23:27:24 GMT
# Filename   : InputStream
# Path       : InputStream
# Pattern    : Last-Modified
# Context    :
# Matches    : {0}
```

The reason youc `$storeddate -ne $lastupdated` always returns `$true` is because a `[string]` and a `[matchinfo]` are *never* equal.

### Workaround

If you want to get a textual (i.e. `[string]`) representation of the return value from `Select-String` you can do this:

```
$lastupdated = invoke-webrequest -uri $source `
    | Out-String -Stream `
    | Select-String Last-Modified `
    | select-object -ExpandProperty "Line"
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - extract the "Line" property value

$lastupated

# Last-Modified     Web 17, May 2023 23:27:24 GMT
```

(note the `select-object -ExpandProperty "Line"` which extracts the value of the `Line` property from the `matchinfo` object)

And now `$lastupdated` really *is* a `[string]` as opposed to a `MatchInfo` and you should find `$storeddate -ne $lastupdated` will correctly return `$false` when they're the same.

### `Last-Modified` Header

Having said all of that, I'm going to take a bit of a leap and guess that you're really actually after the `Last-Modified` response header from your call to `invoke-webrequest` which you can get a lot easier if you do this:

```
$response = invoke-webrequest -uri $source

$lastupdated = $response.Headers["Last-Modified"]

$lastupdated

# Web 17, May 2023 23:27:24 GMT
```

which won't be affected by differences in brittle stringifying of the response before you extract the `Last-Modified` using `select-string`.

And, if you're using the `Last-Modified` header to decide whether a resource has been updated, you might as well use the `HEAD` method as well to avoid downloading the entire resource content, since that's what you're trying to avoid doing in the first place if it's already up to date:

```
$response = invoke-webrequest `
   -Uri    "www.google.com" `
   -Method "HEAD" `
   -UseBasicParsing

$lastupdated = $response.Headers["Last-Modified"]

$lastupdated

# Web 17, May 2023 23:27:24 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastupdated -ne $storeddayed
True
```

Indeed means that the values aren't identical even their **basic properties** (display values) appear to be the same.

PowerShell is a [loosely typed programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) which lets you "convienently" compare two values of a different type. Try this:

```
$lastupdated.GetType()
$storeddayed.GetType()
```

I suspect that the `$storeddayed` variable is actually a string as the name implies that it has been stored were it is has likely lost its fidelity of the actual [`datetime` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime) as it has either been [converted automaticaly](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06) or "manually" as you do in your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76277291/1701026) with the `ToString()` method.
If you compare two different types the objects. The object at the RHS (right hand side) dictates the conversation for the comparison (this generally counts for any other operator).
This means that you might just convert the right side (or both sides) to a string (using double quotes):

```
"$lastupdated" -ne "$storeddayed"
```

Or simply swap the operants in the operation to get what you expected:

```
$storeddayed -ne $lastupdated
```

Also note that in case the operants (`$storeddayed` and `$lastupdated`) are *both* of the `datetime` structure, not all detailed [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime#properties) are displayed by default (think of the timezone information and e.g. the `millisecond` property).

In other words, if you give the commands in one go:

```
$lastupdated = Get-Date()
$storeddayed = Get-Date()
```

They might look the same as you display them (as string) but they actually differ in time:

```
$lastupdated.Millisecond
$storeddayed.Millisecond
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the .ToString() when saving the string to a file and now my operator seems to be working.

```
$lastupdated.ToString() | out-file c:\windows\file.txt
```